Making an App Editable While It’s Open to Public
I am in the process of developing an app that would require new events to be put out every week or so, which means I would need to be able to update this information as I wish. Once my app is open to the public, would I be able to do this or do I need to add something to make it edible like a certain item? Let me know if anything is unclear.
I need to be able to have a page with information that I can delete and replace with new information every so often.

The events can't be in your app itself. Your app will need to fetch eye data from a server. You will then add new events to the server database. You can look at FireStore

An app can't be editable. The source of truth/data can be modified if you have access to it outside of your app with something like the CoreData public database, Firebase, REST, AWS, Azure, etc.
